# Is there an easy way to require an address from a customer when creating an account

Tags: magento

Anyone know the easiest way to require a customer to fill out an address when creating their account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is the address information in the template, which only shows when `$this->getShowAddressFields()` is true. It looks like this is only set for registering when using the multiple shipping addresses, so I just threw `$this->setShowAddressFields(true);` In the top of my template and it works fine. Probably should do this in a block or through an observer though.